# Axios createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Hello I'm developing a react-Node Js app and I'm migrating a component class to a functional component one, now I'm getting the issue: `createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500` the same method worked well in the component class. The next is the code of my react component:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "25ch",
    },
  },
}));

export default function BasicTextFields(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState("");
  const [field, setField] = useState("");
  const [integrationName, setIntegrationName] = useState("");
  const [total, setTotal] = useState("");

  function handleChange(evt, field) {
    setField(evt.target.value);
    console.log("new value", evt.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Event delete:" + event);
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("collection", collection);
    params.append("field", field);
    params.append("integrationName", integrationName);
    var request = {
      params: params,
    };

    console.log("request: 127.0.0.1:" + request);

    axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/firestore/`, request).then((res) => {
      console.log("react1: ", res);
      console.log("react2: ", res.data);
      this.setState({ total: res.data });
    });
  }

  function handleSubmitCount(event) {
    console.log("...count...");
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("collection", collection);
    params.append("field", field);
    params.append("integrationName", integrationName);
    var request = {
      params: params,
    };

    console.log("request 127.0.0.1:" + request);
    console.log("BACKEND_HOST:", process.env);
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/firestore/`, request).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ total: res.data });
    });
  }

  return (
    <span>
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
          name="collection"
          onChange={(e) => setCollection(e.target.value)}
          helperText="Collection"
          variant="outlined"
          required
          margin="dense"
        />
        <TextField
          name="field"
          onChange={(e) => setCollection(e.target.value)}
          helperText="Field"
          variant="outlined"
          required
          margin="dense"
        />

        <TextField
          name="value"
          onChange={(e) => setCollection(e.target.value)}
          helperText="Value"
          variant="outlined"
          required
          margin="dense"
        />
        <br />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
          disableElevation
          type="button"
        >
          Delete Registers
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={(e) => handleSubmitCount(e)}
          disableElevation
          type="button"
        >
          Count Registers
        </Button>

        <br />
        <br />
        <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
          {total}
        </Typography>
      </form>
    </span>
  );
}
```

I'm getting the error, when I click in the button and use the `handleSubmitCount` method, for some reason it is not calling the axios request and it's throwing the issue mentioned before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have passed some months but here it goes... (I have also had the same issue.

You are, most likely, getting an HTTP error code and Axios is rejecting the promise.

You will need to catch it and get the message from the server (if any).

```
axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/firestore/`, request)
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ total: res.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // here you will have access to error.response
        console.log(error.response)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way please

```
function requestObject(url,method, params) {
    let configObject = {
        "url": url,
        "method": method,
        "params": params
        
    }
    return configObject
}

 function handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log("Event delete:" + event);
       let data= {
      "collection": collection, "field" : field, 
      "integrationName":integrationName
};
let configObejct = requestObject("http://127.0.0.1:8081/firestore/", "delete", data);
axios.request(configObejct).then((res) => {
          console.log("react1: ", res);
          console.log("react2: ", res.data);
          this.setState({ total: res.data });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Tue issue is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't work. I got the same 500 code error.

Answer (score 0):

500 is a server error. try examining your error:

```
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8081/firestore/", request).then((res) => {
  this.setState({ total: res.data });
}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Axios documents, you'll find that delete method does not receive a body param which is what you're sendind after that colon. Request must only have a url parameter and an options/configuration param (optional).

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md#axiosdeleteurl-config

I suggest you to make the request like this:

```
axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/firestore/${params.toString()}`).then(callback);
```

As request only contains your params, this object won't be required anymore.

Bear in mind that this params belong to a query string param type, and thats the purpose on URLSearchParams interface.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Given,
`axios.get('').catch(e => console.log(e.response)`

In order to get axios actual response you need to do `e.response`.
Also, in the screenshot you can see e is throws a error text message.
[image]